# Parse Server LiveQuery Subscribe for Multiple contacts and Events (Android)

Tags: android, livequery

I am developing Chatting Application for Android.
I want to Subscribe Live Query for multiple Contacts in _User Class on Online Status of Users.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query= ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");

        SubscriptionHandling<ParseObject> subscriptionHandling = parseLiveQueryClient.subscribe(query);


        subscriptionHandling.handleEvent(SubscriptionHandling.Event.CREATE,
                new SubscriptionHandling.HandleEventCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(ParseQuery<ParseObject> query, ParseObject object) {


                    }
                });
```

This Code works for all Users. But i want to trigger LiveQuery on selected Users.
i want to do something like that... At Run time, WhenEver Application Launches.

```
query.whereEqualsTo("username","USER1");
query.whereEqualsTo("username","USER2");
```

I am using Library
compile 'com.parse:parse-livequery-android:1.0.0'

thanks in Advance

Comment: did u invoke those 2 calls in 'query' before creating the subscription?

Comment: No, i didn't use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late with the reply, but hope it helps others who have encountered the same issue.

The query you should be looking at is: "whereContainedIn"

```
query.whereContainedIn("username", Arrays.asList("USER1", "USER2"));
```

As there are two "whereEqualTo" constraints over the same key - which contradicts itself - Parse will only apply one constraint.

For more information, please look at: https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#limits-and-other-considerations

P.S.: there's also a typo with the language for the constraint. It should be "whereEqualTo", and not "whereEqualsTo".